# Mock Laravel's Config facade to return a value only for a certain key

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mockery

I would like to mock `Config::get('specific_key')` to return a `'specific_value'` in my test. So I wrote the following code:

```
Config::shouldReceive('get')
    ->with('specific_key')
    ->andReturn('specific_value');
Config::makePartial();
```

This will work: if I add `dd(Config::get('specific_key'))` I will receive `'specific_value'`.

However, if I do `dd(Config::get('another_key'))`, I don't receive any value (I guess because the mock doesn't expect this key as an argument).

So my question is: Is there a way to mock Config's get() method to return a specific value only for an specific key (and return normal value from the configuration file for any other key)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't have to mock Config, you can use `Config::set()` to set any value in Config. So `Config::set('specific_key', 'specific_value');` in the test instead of creating the mock should work